# How to execute multiple commands sequentially in unix via Robot framework ?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-sshlibrary

Problem Statement : I want to fire multiple commands on console in the same shell . Not getting correct way to do this. 
Tried with Write and  Write Bare Command ( ssh library) but the getting an undesirable output like there is a change of line . 
Is there anyway I can get the response without line change ? 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you please show us what you've tried?

Comment: Have you tried to execute all scripts with && adding between command. Ex. ‘’’ Robot ./test && cp output.xml reports && la -ltr something like this? ‘’’

Comment: Hi @rishu malani, Did you find any thing on this issue. because I would like to execute multiple commands